# Modified js (javascript) not loaded on the mobile device ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, xamarin.android

The web-based application was developed using the ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1, JQuery, html5, css3. The website is pretty much opened on Xamarin WebView so created a Xamarin Andriod wrapper with webview to open the website. Recently the javascript is modified and uploaded to the Production server to which the mobile app (Xamarin webview) still loads with an older version of javascript. tried with the below options but still did not work.

- Restarted the website
- AppPoll is recycled.
- apply the static changes to the specific JS file directly in the production server.
  but, No luck so far.

One more clue, the same website is working fine in chrome/ edge browser with updated js. thanks

Comment: It could be the case that your mobile app loads a cached version of the script. Maybe try the method described in [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2158104.aspx?How+can+I+force+my+net+core+2+2+web+site+to+refresh+cached+js+files) answer. This will always load the script from the server and not the cached one. I would not do this in production but I guess it could help you to try to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the version at the end which resolved the issue. Whenever you make any changes to the js file, the version can be increased to ensure the updated version of js will be used.

[image]